# Javascript variable is assigned as [object HTMLDivElement] rather than string?

Tags: javascript, dom

My DOM skills are weak and I can't work out why a javascript variable is assigned this object pointer value rather than the string value itself.

Short story is that I am making an AJAX call for some screen data and it returns html and populates a div.innerHTML with the following :

```
 <input id="page_tag_add_input"></input>';

    <span class="page_tag_add"><a href="#" onclick="var newTag = document.getElementById('page_tag_add_input').value; doTagXhr('add_tag.php', newTag); alert(newTag);">Add</a></span>
```

The doTagXhr function is a YUI connection manager AJAX call.

When the user clicks add, firebug shows me that the newTag variable is stored as "[object HTMLDivElement]", yet when the alert(newTag) javascript kicks in (above), it shows the value correctly as the input text string?? I've exhausted Google searches :-(

Are there any gurus out there that can point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning newTag to a DOM Element property. I think you've mistaken what Firebug reports it as, that code indicates it's clearly not an element reference, and unless you're manipulating it in the xhr function ( which you didn't paste the code to ) then it's still a string.

Edit:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function doTagXhr(page, input) {
    window.input = input;
    $.ajax({
        url:page,
        type:'POST',
        data:input
    });
    }
</script>
<input id="page_tag_add_input" value="test">

    <span class="page_tag_add"><a href="#" onclick="var newTag = document.getElementById('page_tag_add_input').value; doTagXhr('regex.php', newTag); alert(newTag);">Add</a></span>
```

This always stays a string. I don't know what else it could be other than your xhr function that's reassigning the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. 

Sorry, maybe I worded that wrong. When I refer to Firebug, I mean to say that I can see the newTag param that is being POSTed and it is sending the string "[object HTMLDivElement]" rather than the value of the input field that I want.

Comment: But yes, your comment about assigning a variable to the DOM Element property sounds interesting. Even if I don't declare a variable and put the getElementById directly into the function call, i.e.:

doTagXhr('add_tag.php', document.getElementById('page_tag_add_input').value)

I get the same issue... hmm? More pondering needed. Also more coffee.

Comment: can you post the code to your xhr function? i replicated what you are trying to do and I'm not experiencing what you are. It has to be that XHR function.

Comment: Lifesaver! User error on my part. My doTagXhr function had an overlap with tag name variables and it was picking up the contents of another html item. Thank you very much!!